# How do I import .jar and use its class and also how do i use stmt from a .jar file in netbeans?

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans, import, jar

It's 1:37am here so I'm greeting you all a good day.

I've got a problem here and I'm really really new to java. Please have patience on me. :(

I've got a .jar file that I imported to my Libraries in my netbeans project. It's called dbconnect.jar. I want to create a statement in my Fruits.java that will change my `stmt` statement (from inside dbconnect.jar) to whatever mysql statement i want it to be (specifically, I want to add fruits to my db). Here's my project map:

[image: my project map]

So inside my dbconnect.jar contains the class `Dbconnect`. Here are the contents of `Dbconnect`:

```
package dbconnect;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class Dbconnect {
    public Connection conn = null;
    public Statement stmt = null;
    public ResultSet rs = null;

public Dbconnect(){
    try{  
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  

        String Host = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/dbname";
        String Username = "root" ;
        String Password = "";

        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(Host, Username, Password);
        stmt = conn.createStatement();

        }catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
                   } 

    }    
}
```

By the way, I'm using xampp for Apache and Mysql.

So my questions are, how do I call/import this `dbconnect.jar` of mine so I can use it in `Fruits.java` (and if possible, am I able to use `extends` here?) and how do I make it so that I can edit the `stmt` part in `dbconnect.jar` using `Fruits.java` ?

This is currently what's inside the add button from my UI in Fruits.java:
[image: inside of add button]

I really need help with this. Thank you so much in advance!
Oh and I'm still a starter. So I hope there will be no advanced codes. Thanks again!

And yes, I'm using JFrame. Here's what it looks like for now.

[image: UI]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since, you have `Dbconnect.jar` on your classpath you can just say something like this in your `Fruit.java` class:

```
Dbconnect db = new Dbconnect();
```

This will create a new object of `Dbconnect` class with name `db`.

In order for you to be able to edit the statement you'll have to create a new method and not just call it in the constructor.

Here is an example:

```
public void connect(String myStatement) {
    /* Do Something */
}
```

You can then call `connect()` function on `db` object you created before.

Comment: oh god heeeey!
Thank you so much for answering.
I got the instantiation part. (I think it's called something like that I forgot) thank you so much!

But I'm still confused with the stmt part. xD

Comment: Oh by the way, I'm practicing for class as my teacher said we need to use our dbconnector apis Dx. So I'll really have to use the dbconnect.jar file. 

I don't quite get the statement part I'm so sorry for being slow

Comment: @NolanKr You'll have to expose either the Setter for `Statement` in the `Dbconnect.jar` or create a new `public` method altogether to pass the variable you want.

Comment: expose the setter? Yeah!! that's what I wanted to do I think.

Ill go search it on google and see if I can get through it!

Thanks and good day/night to you <3

Comment: @NolanKr Your Welcome! :)